# How to make Embeds which reads the data from the message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord bot for announcements. I want to create a command which will read the data from the message and convert it into Embedded message.

An example command: `!announce Title, Description, Link, Image`

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

//listener
bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.user.setGame('Hello!')
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {

if(message.content == 'text') {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

    .setTitle("Title!")
    .setDescription("Description")
    .setImage("https://i.imgur.com/xxxxxxxx.png")
    .setURL("https://google.com")
    .addField("Text", true)

    //Nope
    .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/Rmiwd1j.png")
    .setColor(0x00AE86)
    .setFooter("Footer", "https://i.imgur.com/xxxxxxxx.png")

    .setTimestamp()

    /*
     * Blank field, useful to create some space.
     */      
    message.channel.send({embed});

}});

bot.login('token');
```

I want Embed to be changed based on the text.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to detect the command: you can use [`String.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to detect `!announce`:

```
if (message.content.startsWith('!announce')) {...}
```

Then you'll have to get the other parts of the command by splitting the string: you can separate them with a comma, as you did (title, description, ...), or with whatever character you want (I'll use a comma in my example).
[`String.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) will help you get rid of the `!announce` part, while [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will create an Array with the other parts.

This code will generate an embed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JohJh.png) from the command `!announce Title, Description, http://example.com/, http://www.hardwarewhore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/dcord.png`

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!announce')) {
    let rest_of_the_string = message.content.slice('!announce'.length); //removes the first part
    let array_of_arguments = rest_of_the_string.split(','); //[title, description, link, image]

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle(array_of_arguments[0])
      .setDescription(array_of_arguments[1])
      .setImage(array_of_arguments[3])
      .setURL(array_of_arguments[2])
      .addField("Text", true)
      .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/Rmiwd1j.png")
      .setColor(0x00AE86)
      .setFooter("Footer", array_of_arguments[3])
      .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send({ embed });
  }
});
```

I suggest using the text instead of the description and remind that the second argument of the `.addField()` is the text, not the inline value